# NDSolve: ProcessEquations and Reinitialize with Piecewise functions

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am having trouble with using `` NDSolve`Reinitialize `` when the system consists of a piecewise function.

If we define the ODE system

```
simplesys = {r'[t] == Piecewise[{{1, 0<= t <=10}, {0, 10<= t <=20}}, 0], r[0] == 0};
```

and process the equations with

```
state = First @ NDSolve`ProcessEquations[simplesys, r, t]
```

this works perfectly fine. However, when I try to reinitialize the ODE system with a new initial condition:

```
newstate = NDSolve`Reinitialize[state, {r[0] == 2}]
```

this fails with the message:

```
NDSolve`Reinitialize::ntcs: Cannot solve constraint equations for initial conditions.
```

This is due to the piecewise function in the system. I don't have this problem for other types of systems, and it only occurs when I have a piecewise function. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: In this specific case you can replace `Piecewise[...]` with `UnitStep[10 - t]`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @b.gatessucks. Works absolutely fine now :)

Answer (score 5):

It is quite tricky! `Piecewise[ ]` functions work only with `"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"`... I'll try to dig up why

```
simplesys = {r'[t] == Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= t <= 10}, {0, 10 <= t <= 20}}, 0], r[0] == 0};
state = First@ NDSolve`ProcessEquations[simplesys, r, t, 
                                  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];

newstate = First@NDSolve`Reinitialize[state, {r[0] == 2}];
NDSolve`Iterate[newstate, 20];
sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[newstate];

Plot[Evaluate[r[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 20}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The truth is that the `"Residual"` method doesn't seem to do much work, as it isn't simplifying the equations. I'm not sure if using the pre-processing scheme is a good idea if you're forced to use `"Residual"`

Answer (score 3):

The OP's original code works as is in V10.0.0 through V11:

```
simplesys = {r'[t] == Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= t <= 10}, {0, 10 <= t <= 20}}, 0], r[0] == 0};

{state} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[simplesys, r, t];
```

Here we reinitialize three times and plot the results of each:

```
Module[{newstate, sol},
 GraphicsRow@Table[
   {newstate} = NDSolve`Reinitialize[state, {r[0] == r0}];
   NDSolve`Iterate[newstate, 20];
   sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[newstate];
   Plot[Evaluate[r[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 20}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {0, 20}],
   {r0, {0, 4, 6}}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For V9.0.1, one may use

```
{state} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[Simplify`PWToUnitStep@simplesys, r, t];
```

This is effectively the same thing as suggested in @b.gatessucks' comment.