# NDSolve: Reinitialize fails with If condition

Tags: numerical-integration

I have found a weird problem using If conditions containing an state inequality of the form `state<=`.

First consider the simple ODE with an If condition `t<=2`. We first process the equations.

```
state = First@NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{r'[t] == If[t <= 2, 2, 0], r[0] == 0},r, t]
NDSolve`StateData[SequenceForm["<", 0., ">"]]
```

Then we reinitialize the system by

```
newstate = NDSolve`Reinitialize[state, {r[0] == 1}]
NDSolve`StateData[SequenceForm["<", 0., ">"]]
```

which works absolutely fine. Now consider another ODE system with a slightly different If condition, namely `If[r[t] <= 2, 2, 0]`. We process the equations with

```
state2 = First@NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{r'[t] == If[r[t] <= 2, 2, 0], r[0] == 0},r, t]
NDSolve`StateData[SequenceForm["<", 0., ">"]]
```

which works fine. Now when we try to reinitialize this system we get an error message!

```
newstate2 = NDSolve`Reinitialize[state2, {r[0] == 1}]
NDSolve`Reinitialize::ntcs: Cannot solve constraint equations for initial conditions.
```

It seems like when I try to reinitialize Mathematica has a problem due to the condition `r[t]<=2`. I have noticed the same problem with for example PieceWise functions, as noted in this post:

[NDSolve: ProcessEquations and Reinitialize with Piecewise functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30426/ndsolve-processequations-and-reinitialize-with-piecewise-functions)

Answer (score 2):

I filed this as a bug. Here is a workaround. It's much easier to use `ParametricNDSolve` for this:

```
pf = ParametricNDSolveValue[{r'[t] == If[r[t] <= 2, 2, 0], r[0] == a},
   r, t, a]

pf[0]
pf[1]
```

As an alternative, you could try to experiment with:

```
g[in_?NumericQ] := If[in <= 2, 2, 0]
state2 = First@
   NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{r'[t] == g[r[t]], r[0] == 0}, r, t];
newstate2 = NDSolve`Reinitialize[state2, {r[0] == 1}]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't want to use ParametricNDSolve in this case, since I have found a lot of weird issues regarding ParametricNDSolve (filed to Wolfram Support). Is there any other workaround?

Comment: @jaclea, what exactly is the problem with `ParametricNDSolve` in this case? Perhaps I can help with that.

Comment: I found a lot of issues regarding differentiation ParametricNDSolve objects. For example, you cannot differentiate your system if it includes a matrix differential equation.

I am really in need of using NDSolve`Reinitialize.

Comment: Here is a post regarding this problem:

http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32084/parametricndsolve-fails-to-differentiate-an-matrix-differential-equation

Comment: Filed the above. You speak of a `lot of issues` do you have more?

Comment: let me know if the `g` workaround helps.

Comment: Here is another issue: 

http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32088/paralleltable-of-parametricndsolve-objects-fail