# ParametricNDSolve: Fails to differentiate an matrix differential equation

Tags: numerical-integration, bugs, version-9

It seems like there is a problem with differentiating a ParametricNDSolve object when the underlying system contains an matrix differential equation.

Create a simple ParametricNDSolveValue object which returns x[2], depending on parameter k.

```
pfun1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -k*x[t], x[0] == 10}, x[2], {t, 0, 10}, k]
ParametricFunction[SequenceForm["<", ">"]]
```

Now we have the same system but we add a matrix differential equation independent of the state `x[t]`. Here `P[t]` should be zero for all t due to the inital condition.

```
pfun2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -k*x[t], x[0] == 10, 
P'[t] == P[t], P[0] == {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}}, x[2], {t, 0, 10}, k]
ParametricFunction[SequenceForm["<", ">"]]
```

We can take out the values for `k=0.4`.

```
pfun1[0.4]
pfun2[0.4]
4.49329
4.49329
```

Now we differentiate the systems and take out the value for `k=0.4`.

```
pfun1'[0.4]
pfun2'[0.4]
-8.98658
Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {{0.},{0.},{0.},{0.},{0.}}+{{0.},{-10.}} cannot be combined. >>*
Experimental`NumericalFunction::nlnum1: The function value {{{0.},{-10.}}+{{0.},{0.},{0.},{0.},{0.}}} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {5} when the arguments are {0.,{0.,0.,0.,0.,10.},{0.4},{{0.},{0.},{0.},{0.},{0.}}}.
```

The derivative of the ParametricNDSolveValue object seems to fail when there is a matrix differential equation in the system.

Is this a bug?

Comment: pretty bad; I filed this as a bug.

Answer (score 2):

This was confirmed to be a bug.